# Which passport to use when travelling between south korea and ireland

Tags: passports, south-korea

My daughter will soon have two passports - one korean and one Irish.
I am trying to figure out the correct way to do things but I keep getting told different things.

Ive been told you have to use the passport for that country where you are a citizen meaning enter and exit Ireland on the Irish passport and enter and exit Korea on the Korean passport.

But then I have been told that I have to use the same passport for the total trip which would mean only using the Korean one as we live here.

Which way is correct?

Answer (score 3):

Use the Irish one in and out of Ireland and the Korean one in and out of Korea.

I'm a Dual US/UK Citizen. I always use my US passport for entering the US, but my UK passport everywhere else.

If you're flying from Korea to Ireland and back, you'd use the Irish passport for the flight from Korea to Ireland and the Korean passport for the flight from Ireland to Korea.

Comment: >uk passport everywhere else.  Well, maybe not argentina.

Comment: Actually makes no difference whether I use a US or UK passport for Argentina, neither requires a visa.

Comment: Oh the perks of worldwide anglophilia